# How do you save objects into a google Ui instance.

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What I want to do is save a data-table and an array in the UI instatance, so that the Handler can call on them to do what it is supposed to do. I am fairly new to programming so don't feel bad if you treat this like a stupid question, but please still answer it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to use a hidden widget to store data as string like in this example :

```
function doGet() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var hidden = app.createHidden('hidden').setId('hidden');// widget's name = hidden
//...
  var array = ['item1','item2'] ;

  hidden.setValue(array.toString()); //assign a value as a string
//...
return app
}

function handlerfunction(e){
var array = e.parameter.hidden.split(','); // get the widget's value by its name parameter and reconvert it back to an array
//...
return app
}
```